# Hangfire schedule job gets delayed

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, hangfire

I have a .Net 6 console application using Hangfire to run some recurring jobs that should execute every 15 seconds

I start manually with the following command
`BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Process(watch));`

And at the of end the Process method, if the exit criteria has not been met, I reschedule the same job to be run in 15 seconds like so `BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Process(watch), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));`

Everything runs fine for between 3 to 5 runs, then it will stop for between 1 and 2 minutes, and then it will run fine again for 3/5 runs (never less, never more).
I've tried using RecurringJobs but that's even worse, from the documentation I gathered that's not good for Recurring Jobs < 1 minute

Not sure if this is a platform limitation, or something I'm doing wrong. Currently I only have this 1 job running and nothing else.

I'm using MySQL as the Database, and here are my configurations

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(
    new MySqlStorage(Settings.GetValue("ConnectionString"),
    new MySqlStorageOptions
    {
        TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
        JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
        DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
        TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        TablesPrefix = "Hangfire"
    }));

    Hangfire = new BackgroundJobServer(
           new BackgroundJobServerOptions
           {
               WorkerCount = 15,
               SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
               HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
           });
```

Here is a log example of my code with timestamp

```
2022-02-13 23:15:26.8675|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:15:27.7282|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:15:30.1247|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:15:42.4844|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:15:43.2700|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:15:51.6159|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:15:57.7193|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:15:58.6116|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:16:02.9231|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:16:12.9087|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:16:14.0894|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:17:25.9785|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:17:28.8638|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:17:29.6831|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:17:37.2512|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:17:44.0701|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:17:44.8800|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:17:48.5490|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:17:59.2451|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:18:00.0434|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:18:10.0906|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:18:14.4645|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:18:15.3025|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
2022-02-13 23:19:24.7397|INFO|Hangfire.Server.ServerWatchdog|1 servers were removed due to timeout
2022-02-13 23:19:24.9990|DEBUG|Hangfire.MySql.CountersAggregator|Aggregating records in 'HangfireCounter' table...
2022-02-13 23:19:33.0659|DEBUG|Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler|1 scheduled job(s) processed by scheduler.
2022-02-13 23:19:33.8444|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Checking 12
2022-02-13 23:19:34.7306|DEBUG|mypackage.MyJob|Ended Processing
```

Comment: I would try lowering the HeartBeatInterval to as low as 1 minute (lower than the CountersAggregateInterval in fact)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've tried it, but no help